# Problem with Latex encoding - Force Latex to accept character and ignore Errors?

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings, font-encodings

I have somewhat of an unusual problem.
I'm trying to write the quote

> There are three hard problems in computer science: 1) Converting from PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃

[-- Marseille Folog](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/encoding.html)

In a Latex Document and I get errors like "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ༃ (U+0F03)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX." when compiling with **pdftex**

for a variety of characters:

```
/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳
                                         ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳
                                           ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳
                                             ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳
                                               ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳
                                                 ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ... 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...nverting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...erting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...ting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...ng to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ... to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...o PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳��̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...F, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ... and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Ҙ (U+0498)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...nd 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ
                                                  ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ... 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉
                                                  ҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉
                                                  ҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉
                                                  ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹ
                                                  ʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ
                                                  ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉
                                                  ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨
                                                  ̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨
                                                  ̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳��̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨
                                                  ̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨
                                                  ̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̃ (U+0303)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃
                                                  ༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ༃ (U+0F03)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃
                                                  ༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ༃ (U+0F03)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃
                                                  O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳���...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...ʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  ̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̳ (U+0333)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳
                                                  Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Ҙ (U+0498)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ
                                                  ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉
                                                  ҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...��O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉
                                                  ҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉
                                                  ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹ
                                                  ʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ
                                                  ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃�...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ҉ (U+0489)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉
                                                  ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ʹ (U+02B9)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...�̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ
                                                  ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃ʹ...

/workspace/notebooks/working-example.tex:7: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̨ (U+0328)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Even if I'm very capable of seeing the irony in it, could somebody tell me if there's a way to force the characters? I just want to produce the same effect, which happens using these characters and I have no idea how I can achieve it.
Just putting in a Picture of the quote would kind of ruin the message in my scientific paper...

My not working representation of this Problem (MWE) is:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
There are three hard problems in computer science: 1) Converting from
PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3) O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃༃༃
--Marseille Folog
\end{document}
```

And the result is just:
[image: The gibberish is just replaced with two O's]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: please provide a small _complete_ document that produces the error that you show it is much harder to guess how to debug disconnected fragments. Also do you want this to work with pdftex or xetex or luatex, your question is mostly about font support for weird characters but you give no information about what fonts you are using

Comment: Hi and welcome. Where did you get the `\CYRZDSC` macro? For someone to help you, give him an MWE as instructed here: [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Of Corse - sorry, new here :)

Comment: To be honest, the supplied error code was not the best representation of the errors occuring. I replaced it more elaborately and fitting to the new MWE. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: You won't be able to compile that with `pdflatex`, because the text uses combining characters that `pdflatex` is unable to comply with.

Comment: You'll have to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead. For me, DejaVu Sans and Noto Sans Tibetan give an acceptable result when compared with the original quote on Twitter.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way to get the same effect as seen above with pdflatex (the encoding problems occuring in the md quote above)?
I was hoping for a kind of -f approach or a trick to get the same effect :)

Comment: @Noone thank you,I will try it :)

Comment: You could compile your gibberish text (sorry, not pejorative) using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX via `standalone` and then loading it as an image, but IMO it's a really ugly solutions. As egreg said, pdflatex alone is incapable to deal with your input.

Comment: I suppose you could try stacking them with `substack` or something. But the best approach would probably be to save the graphic you want as an image, such as a standalone PDF, and include it.

Comment: Fundamentally, there is no way to “force LaTeX to accept character.” PDFLaTeX is an 8-bit engine that was hacked to handle precomposed UTF-8 characters. It doesn’t do combining characters. Even if it did, the 8-bit fonts it uses would not contain them. You need a modern engine.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, as others said, `pdf(la)tex` won't work, so you could 1) use another engine, as XeTeX or LuaTeX, or 2) embed a (PDF) output.

The following, after some trial and error, worked for me:

```
%Compile with xelatex or lualatex
%gibberish.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%Other fonts, as Noto, give weirder results
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\makeatletter 
%For Tibetan characters
\newfontfamily\@tibet@{Noto Sans Tibetan}
\newcommand{\tibet}[1]{{\@tibet@ #1}}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃\tibet{༃༃}O̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳̳Ҙ҉҉҉ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃\tibet{༃༃}ʹʹ҉ʹ̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̃\tibet{༃༃}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, if you want to use `pdflatex` anyway, do the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
There are three hard problems in computer science: 1) Converting from PDF, 2) Converting to PDF, and 3)  \includegraphics{gibberish.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :)