# Using Sphinx, how can I tell LaTeX to not process emojis?

Tags: sphinx, emoji

I'm facing errors converting a Sphinx project (read the docs style documentation).

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1F69A)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I've read that it would not be easily  possible to display the emojis in the PDF using LaTeX. For my use case, that's not a prerequisite.
But could I configure Sphinx or Latex to avoid processing emojis when rendering the PDF?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you (presumably) have these characters in the generated tex source, you could filter them out in sphinx or leave them in and declare the ones you use for pdflatex or use lualatex and include an emoji font or ....

Comment: Try switching to an engine that supports unicode and a font, that contains those emojis: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#latex-options

Comment: Maybe [pdftex - Force LaTeX to ignore unknown Unicode characters - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652214/force-latex-to-ignore-unknown-unicode-characters?noredirect=1#comment1625784_652214).