# Force LuaTeX to ignore unknown Unicode characters

Tags: luatex

I am trying to programmatically either filter out or ignore invalid unicode characters, such as U+0002 (␂), not supported by my font that generate "Text line contains an invalid character. A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input." error messages. I don't control the input text so I can't manually remove them and there are too many possible invalid characters to try and explicitly remap them all.

I'm looking for a solution similar to
`\makeatletter\def\UTFviii@undefined@err#1{}\makeatother` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652216/94668) but that works for LuaTeX and not just PdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX is a very complicated program, handling **all** possible input requires testing **all** possible input.

So it's recommended for you to create a file with all the Unicode character from 0 to 1114111 and feed it into your program to test.

For the specific error you pointed out, that error message "A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input" is caused by...

[image: TeX source code]

characters with catcode 15. It's **not because the font doesn't support it**.

Note that LuaTeX has another time where "funny symbol" message is printed, namely:

```c
static void utf_error(void)
{
    const char *hlp[] = {
        "A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.",
        "Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.",
        NULL
    };
    deletions_allowed = false;
    tex_error("String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence", hlp);
    deletions_allowed = true;
}
```

invalid UTF-8 sequence.

In any case, use [Viewing a character's catcode, and listing all characters with a given catcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375940/viewing-a-characters-catcode-and-listing-all-characters-with-a-given-catcode) we can view a list of all characters with category code 15:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\charcount
\charcount=0
\loop\ifnum\charcount<1114112 % Change to 256 if not using XeTeX/LuaTeX
  \ifnum\catcode\charcount=15
    Character \number\charcount \ has category code \number\catcode\charcount .

  \fi
  \advance\charcount by 1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

the output is that the only characters are 0 → 31 and 127. That is, precisely the [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

If you're generating the file automatically, the easiest way appears to be filtering them all out in advance.

---

Of course, after doing this, you may still encounter issues with `%` and `\` etc.  There are certain solutions that does not rely on category code to typeset text, such as https://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX (but I assume they're not as easy to learn)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

ctrl-A []

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.5 ctrl-A [^^A
           ]
?
```

The classic approach would be to make the control characters printable so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\count0=-1
\loop
\advance\count0 by 1
\ifnum\count0=9 \advance\count0 by 2 \fi
\ifnum\count0=13 \advance\count0 by 1 \fi
\catcode\count0=12
\ifnum\count0<31
\repeat
\count0=0

\begin{document}

ctrl-A []

\end{document}
```

which treats them like normal characters that are (probably) not in the font, so a warning

```
Missing character: There is no ^^A (U+0001) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
```

and output

[image]

Latin Modern would show nothing, some fonts show a missing glyph marker.

Or you could replace all control characters in a Lua callback:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\directlua{
  function replacectrl (s)
%   return s:gsub("[\@percentchar c]","^^^^fffd") latin modern doesn't have �
   return s:gsub("[\@percentchar c]","?")
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',replacectrl,'replace control chars')
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

ctrl-A []

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]